# Rails: Query to get recent items based on the timestamp of a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have the usual polymorphic associations for comments:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I'd like to be able to define Book.recently_commented, and Article.recently_commented based on the created_at timestamp on the comments. Right now I'm looking at a pretty ugly find_by_SQL query to do this with nested selects. It seems as though there must be a better way to do it in Rails without resorting to SQL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

For what it's worth, here's the SQL:

```
select * from 
    (select books.*,comments.created_at as comment_date 
    from books inner join comments on books.id = comments.commentable_id 
    where comments.commentable_type='Book' order by comment_date desc) as p 
group by id order by null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your method has looked like previously but I'd start with:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.recently_commented
    self.find(:all, 
              :include => :comments, 
              :conditions => ['comments.created_at > ?', 5.minutes.ago])
  end
end
```

This should find all the books that have had a comment created on them in the last 5 minutes. (You might want to add a limit too).

I'd also be tempted to create a base class for this functionality to avoid repeating the code:

```
class Commentable < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  def self.recently_commented
    self.find(:all, 
              :include => :comments, 
              :conditions => ['comments.created_at > ?', Time.now - 5.minutes])
  end
end

class Book < Commentable
end

class Article < Commentable
end
```

Also, you might want to look at using a plugin to achieve this. E.g. [acts_as_commentable](http://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable).

Comment: you could refactor Time.now - 5.minutes by 5.minutes.ago :)

Comment: Thanks, this got me there! I am using acts_as_commentable, so my next task is to add it to the plugin so I don't have to repeat it for every type.

Comment: No problem. Updated to include the `.ago` refinement too.

Comment: I changed things slightly to add :order => 'comments.created_at desc' so things show up with the most recently commented items first.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's just best to add a field to the object of which you are commenting. Like maybe a commented_at field of datetime type. When a comment is made on an object, simply update that value.

While it is possible to use SQL to do it, The commented_at method may prove to be much more scalable.

Comment: Yes, that may the way I end up going. The code would be much easier to understand.

Comment: Quick update - for performance reasons adding the commented_at field to the object became necessary. In the 'commented' callback, I also disable the record_timestamps so that updated_at is not changed when the object is commented.